# Populating imageview on tableviewcell from Api response

Tags: uitableview, imageview

I am new to ios and implementing swift 3 first time.I have a json of the following kind:

```
[ homeCatArray =     (
                {
            "child_id" = 25;
            image = "HTTP://i.vinove.com/dnn/backend/uploads/banner_saldi_en.png";
            name = "WINTER SALE";
            "parent_id" = 1;
        },
                {
            "child_id" = 4;
            image = "HTTP://i.vinove.com/dnn/backend/uploads/BM_ONDEMAND_EN_NOLOC.jpg";
            name = "FRESH FASHION";
            "parent_id" = 2;
        },
                {
            "child_id" = 11;
            image = "HTTP://i.vinove.com/dnn/backend/uploads/1458204097e-commerce-banner.png";
            name = "";
            "parent_id" = 2;
        },
                {
            "child_id" = 3;
            image = "HTTP://i.vinove.com/dnn/backend/uploads/1458204597banner-4.jpg";
            name = "";
            "parent_id" = 2;
        }
    );
}, "message": Successfull]
```

I have used the following code to fetch it from server.

```
 func webHelper(_ jsonRequest:[String:Any] , url: String ,completionHandler: @escaping CompletionHandler) {

        var request = URLRequest(url:URL(string:url)! )
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        var dataString = NSString()

        let a = "json_data="

        let data = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: jsonRequest, options: [])

        let b = String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)

        let first = a  + b!
        dataString = first as NSString
        dataString = dataString.replacingOccurrences(of: ">",with:"%3E") as NSString

        dataString = dataString.replacingOccurrences(of: "<", with:"%3C") as NSString
        dataString = dataString.replacingOccurrences(of: "&" ,with:"%26") as NSString
        dataString = dataString.replacingOccurrences(of: "'", with:"%E2%80%98") as NSString
        dataString = dataString.replacingOccurrences(of: "£" ,with:"%C2%A3") as NSString
        dataString = dataString.replacingOccurrences(of: "€" ,with:"%u20AC") as NSString
        dataString = dataString.replacingOccurrences(of: "¥" ,with:"%C2%A5") as NSString
        dataString = dataString.replacingOccurrences(of: "₹" ,with:"%u20B9") as NSString
        dataString = dataString.replacingOccurrences(of: "\n", with:"") as NSString
        dataString = dataString.replacingOccurrences(of: "\r" ,with:"") as NSString

        let requestData = dataString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
        request.httpBody = requestData
        request.addValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept-Encoding")
        request.addValue("en-US", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept-Language")
        request.addValue(String(requestData!.count), forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
         let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest){ data,response,error in
            if error != nil{
                print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Error")
                let  dict:[String:AnyObject] = Dictionary()
                completionHandler(dict ,false)

                return
            }

            do {
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary

                if let parseJSON = json {
                    let resultValue = parseJSON["code"] as! Int;

                    if resultValue == 200{
                        completionHandler(parseJSON as! Dictionary ,true)
                    }else{
                        let  dict:[String:AnyObject] = Dictionary()
                        completionHandler(dict ,false)
                    }
                }
            } catch let error as NSError {
                print(error)
                let  dict:[String:AnyObject] = Dictionary()
                completionHandler(dict ,false)
            }
        }
        task.resume()


    }
```

I have obtained the desired result that is the value against key "image" as follows:

```
WebServiceHelper.sharedInstance.webHelper(["method":"home"], url: webServicesUrl) {
            (response, success)
            in
            print("##########",[response["data"]!])
            if (response["data"] as? [String:Any]) != nil{
                print("true")
                let data = response["data"] as? [String:Any]
                let homeData = data?["homeCatArray"] as? [[String:Any]]
                print("#$%#@",homeData!)
                for item in homeData! {

                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                         self.content = [item["image"] as! String]
                        self.tableView.reloadData()

                    }
                }
                 print("1111111Content",self.content)
            }
            else{
                print ("false")
            }
```

and then tring to populte the imageview on tableview cell as follows:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
     let homeCell  = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:"cell") as! HomeTVCustomCells

        // or jpg

        if(content.count > 0){
            let imgURL = URL.init(string:content[indexPath.row])
            let testImage = NSData(contentsOf: imgURL!)
        homeCell.homeTVImageView.image = UIImage.init(data: testImage as! Data)
        }
        else{
            homeCell.homeTVImageView.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "bags")
        }

        return homeCell
     }
}
```

The problem I am facing is ,the service is actually returning four images but even after relaoding the table view every time in loop I am able to see one image only on the tableviewcell imageview.
I don't know where I am going wrong.Kindly give some directions.Any help or guidance would be appreciated .Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing wrong in following lines.

```
for item in homeData! {

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                     self.content = [item["image"] as! String]
                    self.tableView.reloadData()

                }
            }
```

For every iteration you are just assigning new image to self.content. Your self.content should be some array so that you can store all the images. You can do something like below.

```
for item in homeData! {
      self.content.append([item["image"] as! String])
            }
DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
```

Comment: i have tried this code ...but still same issue..all the 5customcell rows of tableview,gets populated with one image where it is expected to get populated by different images.

Comment: how you declared/initialised your content property?

Comment: Sir,I  fixed it ..the real issue was in numberofrows delegate method.Thanks a lot.